# Cloud Storage API doesn't work when deploy on Google Cloud Functions using Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

This work perfectly in local serve with firebase :

```
const gCloudConfig = {
  projectId: 'XXXX-X1234',
  keyFilename: './key.json'
}
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')(gCloudConfig);
const storageBucket = Storage.bucket(bucketUrl);

storageBucket.upload(file.path, {destination: file.name})
  .then(() => {
    //
  });
```

But this doesn't work when i deploy to firebase :

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const storageBucket = Storage.bucket(bucketUrl);

storageBucket.upload(file.path, {destination: file.name})
  .then(() => {
    //
  });
```

I put this line after the `admin.initializeApp(...)`, since i saw that it fixed the problem for someone, but it still doesn't work.

I've tried a lot of stuff :

```
const gCloudConfig = { projectId: 'XXXX-X1234' };
const gCloudConfig = { key: API_KEY };
const gCloudConfig = { key: API_KEY, projectId: 'XXXX-X1234' };
const gCloudConfig = functions.config().firebase;
```

I'm kinda lost, please help me !

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you just initialize the Firebase Admin SDK with its default credentials, then access the Cloud Storage APIs via that.  There's no need to initialize Storage on its own.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket()
bucket.upload(localPath, {
    destination: remotePath
})
```

Here, `bucket` is your project default storage bucket, just like you would have gotten it from the Cloud Storage API.

Note that the no-argument init of the Admin SDK is available when using firebase-functions@1.0.0 or later (current 1.0.2).